# ASP.NET removing an item from Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, session-variables

Which method is preferred?

```
Session.Remove("foo");

Session["foo"] = null;
```

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

> Is there a difference?

There is.
`Session.Remove(key)` deletes the entry (both key & value) from the dictionary while `Session[key] = null` assigns a value (which happens to be null) to a key.  After the former call, the key won't appear in the `Session#Keys` collection.  But after the latter, the key can still be found in the key collection.

Comment: InProc session state is known to be highly unstable under load. If it's abused (happens all the time), then Session["foo"] = null will perform better than Session.Remove["foo"]. The garbage collector should clean up the mess of excessive session variables.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is old thread but definitely stick with `Session["key"] = null` - it's much more faster! I've done some tests (on InProc Session State), removing 1000 items in row (elapsed time is for 1000 items totally, so if you want average time for one item, just divide it with 1000):

Removing 1000 existing items:

```
Session[key] = null; - 0.82380000000000009 ms
Session.Remove(key); - 59.960100000000004 ms
```

Removing 1000 NOT existing items:

```
Session[key] = null; - 1.5368000000000002 ms
Session.Remove(key); - 0.6621 ms
```

Removing 500 existing and 500 not existing items:

```
Session[key] = null; - 1.0432000000000001 ms
Session.Remove(key); - 33.9502 ms
```

Here is a piece of code for first test:

```
Session.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    Session[i.ToString()] = new object();

Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    Session[i.ToString()] = null;
sw1.Stop();

Session.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    Session[i.ToString()] = new object();

Stopwatch sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    Session.Remove(i.ToString());
sw2.Stop();
```

Comment: Is any reason to have 1000 items in session?

Comment: @zgnilec I agree with you but i think JakubRi just want to compare speed of both and show us, except that I think the programming world is huge and can't anyone talk about coding way explicitly. This answer is not related to my current project but I think it deserve +1.

Comment: @zgnilec It is unlikely there will be that many items PER session, but it's a way to test the process OVER 1000 sessions, each belonging to a different user.

Answer (score 11):

It has the same effect. I personally think that the `Session.Remove` method does express the programmer's intent better.

Here some links to the documentation on MSDN:

- [HttpSessionState Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx)
- [HttpSessionState.Item Property (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dhkksh8.aspx)

*"HttpSessionState.Item Property:

Property Value
Type: System.Object


The session-state value with the specified name, or null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the item does not exist."*

Answer (score 10):

I would go with Remove but can not honestly say if there is a difference.  At a guess there may still be an empty key kept for that null value but not sure.  Remove would give me little doubt and if that's what you want to do it **reads better** in code as well.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest difference is how you read from session.

```
if(Session.ContainsKey["foo"]) { return Session["foo"]; }
```

or

```
if(Session["foo"] != null) { return Session["foo"]; }
```

If you use the first method, setting the value to null will not work, and you should use remove.

If you use the second method, you can set the value to null.

Comment: HttpSessionState doesn't have ContainsKey