# How to Remove a Session Using Reset button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session

Goal:
Remove the session of SearchData by pressing the reset button.

Problem:
Is it possible to do it?

Info:
The address "[ASP.NET removing an item from Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261920/asp-net-removing-an-item-from-session) "doesn't tell me how to use reset button to remove the session!

```
HTTPContext.Session["SearchBoat"]



@using (Html.BeginForm("Boat", "Shipments", FormMethod.Post))
{
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />

        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `reset` button, is a [Form Reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) button, that will only empty your form fields, if you want that button to be pressed as well and **actually post a form**, you have several ways:

way **1** (2 forms):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Boat", "Shipments"))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reset", "Shipments"))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Reset" />
}
```

way **2** (add `name` and check that):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Boat", "Shipments"))
{
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Reset" />
}

public ActionResult Shipments(FormCollection form) 
{
    if(form["submitButton"] == "Reset") {
        // reset was pressed
        Session.Remove("SearchBoat"); // remove session
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); // redirect
    }

    // submit was pressed
}
```

way **3** (through an `ActionNameSelectorAttribute`):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111222/28004

---

P.S. No need to specify `FormMethod.Post` as that's the default value.