# Log-out operation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, logout

I've created my login using simple session element. I need a logout process as simple as i did. How can i create Log-out in harmony with my Log-in codes? Thanks in advance.

Here is my model below;

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

and also my controller is below;

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session["User"] = null;
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel data)
    {
        string user = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        if (data.UserName == user && data.Password == password)
        {
            Session["User"] = "1";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            data.ErrorMessage = "Incorrect password or username entered. Please try again.";
            return View(data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your definition of *"the user is logged in"* is *"The UserID is stored in `Session["User"]`"*, then logging out is equally trivial: just clear the session variable, as explained in [ASP.NET removing an item from Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261920/asp-net-removing-an-item-from-session):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    Session.Remove("User");
}
```